# ASP.NET Core Create Outlook Calendar Reminder with Create Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC, C#, EntityFramework Code First and SQL Server 2016.

I have a web form for users to fill out. The end user must enter their first and last names, select their department from a drop down list and select a date value from a drop down list.

Once the end user submit's their data a confirmation page is shown with the values they entered and selected. Is there a way to generate an Outlook calendar file on the confirmation page. So when they click that file it adds a calendar reminder based on the date they selected from the drop down list.

I'm going to post my code if needed.

**Models**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class WinTenDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WinTenDbContext(DbContextOptions<WinTenDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.LastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasKey(d => d.DepartmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .Property(d => d.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .HasKey(a => a.AppointmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .Property(a => a.TimeSlot)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class EmployeeFormVM
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your First Name")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Last Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Department")]
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Appointment")]
    [Display(Name = "Appointment")]
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeesController**

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private readonly WinTenDbContext _context;

    public EmployeesController(WinTenDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
        ViewData["FirstNameSortParm"] = sortOrder == "fname" ? "fname_desc" : "fname";
        ViewData["LastNameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lname_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DeptNameSortParm"] = sortOrder == "deptname" ? "deptname_desc" : "deptname";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "time_slot" ? "time_slot_desc" : "time_slot";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        var employees = from s in _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Appointment).Include(e => e.Department)
                        select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            employees = employees.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "fname":
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName);
                break;
            case "fname_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstName);
                break;
            case "lname_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                break;
            case "deptname":
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.Department.Name);
                break;
            case "deptname_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.Department.Name);
                break;
            case "time_slot":
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.Appointment.AppointmentID);
                break;
            case "time_slot_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.Appointment.AppointmentID);
                break;
            default:
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        return View(await PaginatedList<Employee>.CreateAsync(employees.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
    }

    // GET: Employees/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .Include(e => e.Appointment)
            .Include(e => e.Department)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Confirmation/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Confirmation(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees.Include(d => d.Department).Include(a => a.Appointment)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
        var appointments = _context.Appointments.Include(x => x.Employees).Where(x => !x.Em‌​ployees.Any()).ToLis‌​t();

        var viewModel = new EmployeeFormVM
        {
            Departments = departments,
            Appointments = appointments
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeFormVM employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emp = new Employee();
            {
                emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
                emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
                emp.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;
                emp.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
            }

            // Query DB to check if Employee exists with same First/Last Name
            Employee existingEmployee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == employee.FirstName && m.LastName == employee.LastName);
            if (existingEmployee != null)
            {
                // Display Error if duplicate employee
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An employee with this name has already registered. Please contact the Service Desk for any scheduling conflicts.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                //employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            // Query DB to check if appointment has already been assigned to an employee
            Employee existingAppointment = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AppointmentID == employee.AppointmentID);
            if (existingAppointment != null)
            {
                // Display error if the appointment was already chosen
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This appointment has already been taken. Please select another timeslot.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                //employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            _context.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            var newlyCreatedId = emp.EmployeeID;
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Confirmation), new { id = newlyCreatedId });
        }
        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employeevm = new EmployeeFormVM();
        {
            Employee employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employeevm.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID;
            employeevm.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            employeevm.LastName = employee.LastName;

            // Retrieve list of Departments
            var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
            employeevm.Departments = departments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;

            // Retrieve list of Appointments
            var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
            employeevm.Appointments = appointments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
        }
        return View(employeevm);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EmployeeFormVM vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee employee = _context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == vmEdit.EmployeeID);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employee.FirstName = vmEdit.FirstName;
            employee.LastName = vmEdit.LastName;
            employee.DepartmentID = vmEdit.DepartmentID;
            employee.AppointmentID = vmEdit.AppointmentID;

            try
            {
                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EmployeeExists(vmEdit.EmployeeID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(vmEdit);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .Include(e => e.Appointment)
            .Include(e => e.Department)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        _context.Employees.Remove(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Employees.Any(e => e.EmployeeID == id);
    }
}
```

**Create View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "validation-summary-errors" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AppointmentID, new SelectList(Model.Appointments, "AppointmentID", "TimeSlot"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

**Confirmation View**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="~/images/confirm.png" />
    <h2>Thank you @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)!</h2>    
    <p>Your <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Appointment.TimeSlot)</b> appointment has been booked. If you need to reschedule this appointment, please call the Service Desk at x1380.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need an action capable of generating an *.ics file. It will be a simple text file, with iCal tags. There's libraries such as [ical.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net), which you can use to generate this text, but you could just as easily use a `StringBuilder`. The end result will look something like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ZContent.net//Zap Calendar 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Abraham Lincoln
UID:2008-04-28-04-15-56-62-@americanhistorycalendar.com
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=2;BYMONTHDAY=12
DTSTART:20080212
DTEND:20080213
DTSTAMP:20150421T141403
CATEGORIES:U.S. Presidents,Civil War People
LOCATION:Hodgenville\, Kentucky
GEO:37.5739497;-85.7399606
DESCRIPTION:Born February 12\, 1809\nSixteenth President (1861-1865)\n\n\n
 \nhttp://AmericanHistoryCalendar.com
URL:http://americanhistorycalendar.com/peoplecalendar/1,328-abraham-lincol
 n
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

As you can see, it would be easy enough to generate this, simply filling in your specific event information where appropriate. This format is based on [RFC 5545](https://icalendar.org/RFC-Specifications/iCalendar-RFC-5545/), so give the specification a peruse if you want more info.

However you generate this, your action then would simply take an event id, or something, generate the iCal formatted text, and then return it as a result:

```
public IActionResult CreateICal(int eventId)
{
    var evt = db.Events.Find(eventId);

    // generate iCal from event instancce

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(icalText);
    return File(bytes, "text/calendar", $"{evt.Name}.ics");
}
```

Then, on your confirmation page, you'd simply create a link to this action with appropriate event id and/or any other information you need to pass to the action to create the iCal.

Comment: Thank you for replying to this post. The Action method you supplied, i'm assuming the eventId should be the EmployeeID in my case? Are there Namespaces that I need to add to my project? Also, the values for the date are all listed in a drop down list for the user to select. The values are listed as **Nov 08, 2017 - Morning Slot 2**. So, I'm not sure how I can make a calendar event based on that data. Nov 08, 2017 may work, but not sure how to display the rest such as Morning Slot 2.

Comment: It's just a simplified example to illustrate the point. Whatever data you need to create the iCal data, you would pass to this action. You then use the passed in data, either directly or to look up stuff from some data store to then build the iCal with.

Comment: Ok, I will play around with what you have provided to see if I can figure it out. When the user submits his/her data it goes directly to a confirmation page showing the values they entered and selected from the drop drop down list. Can you please show me how the link should be formatted on the confirmation view that calls the calendar action method?